# If $[L : K ] = n$, then for every irreducible polynomial $f$ is $\operatorname{deg}(f) \le n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

If a field extension is finite with degree $n$, how can I proof that every irreducible polynomial has a degree smaller then $n$. I guess that this is valid, but I am not sure how to proof this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is false.

Consider $L=K=\mathbb{Q}$ then $n=1$ but $x^{2}+1$ is irreducible
of degree $2>1$

Answer (score 0):

Your question may be restated as something like this: ¿ If $[L:K]=n$ then for all $f\in K[x]$ irreducible, $deg(f)\leq n$?.

As Belgi said this is false, the only thing that you can say is this (under the same hypothesis) :

If $f\in K[x]$ is irreducible and has a root in $L$ then $deg(f)\leq n$. For if $u$ is a root of $f$ then $K(u)\subseteq L$ and $[L:K]=[L:K(u)][K(u):K]=[L:K(u)]deg(f)$.